# OVERRIDE="-Dplan.override $2"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In a shell script what does the following mean?

```
OVERRIDE="-Dplan.override $2"
```

Are we assigning the value of the second argument to the program to the `OVERRIDE` variable and creating a new environment variable `plan.override` with value of `OVERRIDE`?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new variable OVERRIDE with the content `-Dplan.override $2` - `$2` stands for the second argument your shell script was given. The variable is only usable within your shell script, not outside of it.

Example:

```
$ ./your-script.sh firstarg secarg
 -> OVERRIDE will have the value -Dplan.override secarg
```

If you want to make OVERRIDE global, use export in your script:

```
export OVERRIDE="-Dplan.override $2"
```

Then source your script from your shell, like

```
$ source your-script.sh firstarg secarg
```

Then your variable OVERRIDE is globally available:

```
$ echo $OVERRIDE
-Dplan.override secarg
```

Comment: that means that -D is not treated as any option but meare addition to the value being assigned. ie. it has no special meaning.